Export data from excel to txt, csv, or json
I am implementing an application in Python that read a specific excel file then export to 1 of 3 types of file (depend which type we choose in the application). In this application, I also design a GUI that have a button with a command that called the below function as well as a Combobox to choose 1 of 3 types of file (txt, csv, json). Here are my following code in Python for the exporting function
def export(self):
        #Export data 
        if self.filepath:
            try:
                df = pd.read_excel(self.filepath)

                export_format = self.file_choice.get()

                export_path = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(self.filepath), os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(self.filepath))[0] + '.' + export_format))

                print(f"Exporting to: {export_path}")

                if export_format == 'json':
                    df.to_json(export_path, orient='records', lines=True)
                elif export_path == 'csv':
                    df.to_csv(export_path, index=False)
                elif export_path == 'txt':
                    df.to_csv(export_path, index=False, sep='\t', header=True)

                self.label_file_explorer.configure(text=f"File exported to: {export_path}")
                self.label_file_explorer.place(x=110, y=350)

            except Exception as e:
                self.label_file_explorer.configure(text=f"Error: {e}")
                self.label_file_explorer.place(x=110, y=350)
        else:
            self.label_file_explorer.configure(text="No file selected.")
            self.label_file_explorer.place(x=110, y=350)

However, the problem I have encountered is when I choose type of file to export into and hit the export button, it does not show up in my choosen directory.
I have been testing and find that the problem comes from the if statement. When I define the first if with json like the above block of code, and then hit the export button, the exported json file will be display in my choosen directory. However, when I choose txt or csv to export into, the file does not appear in my choosen directory. I don't really understand since when it comes to the if statement, if it does not satisfy a first condition, then it must have jump to the next condition and check and so on. But in this case, it is very strange.
Can someone help me with this problem? Any help would be very appreciated. Thank you.

The first if statement is export_format;
The last two if statement are export_path.

Thank you for your help. I was so silly by not looking carefully at the variable.
